# How to do following in Entity Framework 4.1 using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first

[image: Following is the data model]

Assume the above given data model, how to execute following query in EF 4.1

```
Select 
   students.firstname
   ,students.lastname
   ,classes.classname
   ,IsNull(studentsclasses.id,0) Attending 
from students
cross join classes 
left outer join studentsclasses on studentsclasses.classid = classes.classid 
            and studentsclasses.studentid = students.studentid
where students.studentid = 5
```

following is my attempt

```
from s in Students
from c in Classes
select new {
              StudentFirstName = s.Firstname,
              StudentLastName = s.Lastname,
              ClassName = c.Classname
           }
```

Answer (score 3):

In Entity Framework the relationship between `students` and `classes` should be represented by a navigation property `classes` in each `student` Entity that contains all the classes the student is related to. Using this you can do:

```
var student = Students.FirstOrDefault( s = > s.studentid == 5);
if(student!=null)
{
  var studentClasses = student.classes.Select( c => new
  {
     StudentFirstName = student.Firstname,
     StudentLastName = student.Lastname,
     ClassName= c.Classname     
  });
  //..
}
```

Comment: the question is the third column I was able to make a join on two classes. But, in EF 4.1 you dont have intermediate class.So, I was not able to get the value of third column.

Comment: @Mohit: what 3rd column are you referring to?

Comment: i am sorry the forth column. look at following query 

Select 
   students.firstname
   ,students.lastname
   ,classes.classname
   ,IsNull(studentsclasses.id,0) Attending 
from students
cross join classes 
left outer join studentsclasses on studentsclasses.classid = classes.classid 
            and studentsclasses.studentid = students.studentid
where students.studentid = 5